# How to set different type of css button to always have same size in responsive web?

Tags: html, css

The following code is for header in responsive website.

```
[https://codepen.io/Velocodes/pen/rGOJmM][1]
```

Button "AAAAA", "BBBBB", "DDDDD", and "FFFFF" are redirect buttons.
Button "CCCCC" and "EEEEE" are dropdown buttons.

I couldn't figure out what preventing the "CCCCC" and "EEEEE" button to appear the same/similar size with the other buttons.

I want them to always have same size of clickable area with the other buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have those two in another `<div>` element, and the class with the padding is on the div instead of the `<a>`, as it is with the other buttons.